# Non-servlets obtaining properties from web.xml

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

Are there any drawbacks to non-servlets java classes obtaining property values from web.xml?

There are not many examples online; I was wondering if this was an advisable path?

Answer (score 0):

It's just an unnecessary dependency. It's easier to get property values from a properties file in the classpath and it doesn't require the code to run in a servlet container.

Reading the properties from web.xml will require your classes to access a `ServletConfig`, so your classes will all be dependent on servlets. You will be a lot better off with a properties file.

Comment: Hi Nathan:The java class already exist in a Tomcat but are not servlets - I was wondering if these java class should piggy-back using the web.xml for property values, rather than creating a new properties file?

Comment: user353829, as Nathan was saying, don't put the values in the web.xml. put them in a properties file. Then have the servlet (and other class) read the values from that. You should really be thinking/asking why the business logic that reads values is in the Servlet, and not in a service class, making the servlet very lightweight and the service easier to test. Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

One pattern for non-servlet classes to lookup something already defined in web.xml is through the use of JNDI properties(For instance, some shared/cluster level attribute that defines whether this is a Dev/Test/Production environment).

The use cases are more granular and different from the ones defined in properties file.  For vast majority of usecases, looking up from a property file is sufficient.